# Unable to connect to SQL Server session database exception - All pooled connections were in use

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, connection-string, connection-pooling

I am suddenly getting this error, on production, in my log file:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.
>
> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server session database.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I looked at a lot of other answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435582/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-session-database)

but I don't have connections leak and I don't want only to set the max pool to
200 or so because I want to understand why I suddenly get this exception...

These are my connection strings:

```
<!--Nhibernate-->
<add name="name" 
     connectionString="Server= servername;Initial Catalog=DBname;UID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 

<!--Entity Framework-->
<add name="name" 
     connectionString= "metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;initial catalog=DBname;user id=userName;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**Update**

An example of using db without connections leaks:

```
using (var db = new dbName())
{
    using (var connection = db.Database.Connection)
    {
       var command = connection.CreateCommand();

       ...

       connection.Open();

       using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
       {
          ...
          reader.NextResult();
          ...
          reader.NextResult();
          ...
          reader.NextResult();
          ...
       }

       connection.Close();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

It turns out that I indeed had **a connections leak** in Entity Framework,
a place that didn't use `using`, and the connections didn't closed!

Example:

```
private DbContext context = new DbContext();

...

List<dbObject> SeriesEvents = context.dbObject.Where(e => e.RecurrenceId == entity.RecurrenceId).ToList();
```

the `context` variable is not getting closed.

I more thing is that this query made a lot of DB queries more than a 100.

Comment: And let's see the code that supposedly `don't have connections leak` I bet you are not disposing properly

Comment: @Charlieface  you are wrong I am disposing properly. I will update an example

Comment: What does the implementation of the `db.Database.Connection` property look like? Connection does return a proper [DbConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection?view=net-5.0), right?

Comment: How many connections did you have in the SQL Server when the error occurred? Is it likely you have > 32,000 connections at any given time on that Sql Server?

Comment: @rene the implementation of db.Database.Connection is of Entity Framework not mine
I linked the implementation here: http://prntscr.com/10l66fa
the connections is more then 100 and from what I know the default  max pool connections is 100

Comment: Is that sql server running on the same box or is it on a separate server? What is the OS the webserver/client is running on?  Any chance the nHiberbate context is leaking connections instead of this EF one? Does it throw this exception on several places where a connection is created or always at the same method in your code?

Comment: @rene the sql-server is running on the same box. the OS is Windows  2016
I use the same pattern In nHiberbate also. it throw this exception on several places..

Comment: Depending on if sql server will use tcp sockets as well, could you have exhausted all sockets? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/settings-that-can-be-modified-to-improve-network-performance ?

Comment: @rene I will check it

Comment: @rene the amount of available sockets is more than 16 thousand

Comment: I've encountered this kind of error in entity framework due to table locking. You may be able to resolve it by using different transaction isolation settings.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issues in my case by making use of read uncommitted and snapshot isolation for all read-only database access code. It most likely means somewhere an update is trying to occur against a table that it locked by another transaction. This contention tends to exhaust available pool connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this kind of connection pooling issues come with connection leaks. There can be some exceptions happening in DB operations and Connection might not be closed properly.
Please add a try{} catch{} finally{} block and close the connection in the finally block.

If you use the `using`, then the try catch finally is implicit and runtime itself will close the connection. So you need not explicitly close the connection. If using the `using` block, please remove `connection.Close()` from your code.

`Using` statement is actually syntactic sugar for try{} catch{} finally{} where the connection is closed and disposed in finally by runtime.

```
try
{
     connection.Open();
     // DB Operations
}
finally
{
     connection.Close();                
}
```

Comment: form what I checked the using is enough, isn't it ?

Comment: they claim they wrapped their connection in a `using` and the compiler generates a try/catch in that case guaranteeing dispose will be called. Adding a try/catch will not help if their code is correctly implementing a using statement.

Comment: In that case, please remove the connection.close() in your code, as it is maned by the using automatically.

Comment: @Habeeb you are correct that the connection.close() is redundant I will remove it

Comment: @Ben.S did this solve your issue. if so please upvote the answer to help others find the solution.

Comment: @Habeeb I am still checking I will upvote immediately when I will know the answer, you can upvote the question :)  if you think it is good

Comment: I Accept this answer because **in the end it turned out to be a connection leak problem**

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests the problem occurs with the session state database but the information you've provided is for the application connections. There is a different pool for session state due to the different connection string.

Common causes for the session state issues are 1) the instance(s) hosting session state database is undersized for the workload or 2) the session state cleanup job causes long-term blocking.

The cleanup job in earlier .NET versions deleted all expired sessions in a single batch and notorious for causing long-term blocking on a busy site, especially when session state is use heavily:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DeleteExpiredSessions
AS
    DECLARE @now datetime
    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()

    DELETE [ASPState].dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    WHERE Expires < @now

    RETURN 0
```

Later .NET versions use a cursor for the delete to greatly improve concurrency.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DeleteExpiredSessions
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW 

    DECLARE @now datetime
    SET @now = GETUTCDATE() 

    CREATE TABLE #tblExpiredSessions 
    ( 
        SessionId nvarchar(88) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    )

    INSERT #tblExpiredSessions (SessionId)
        SELECT SessionId
        FROM [ASPState].dbo.ASPStateTempSessions WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
        WHERE Expires < @now

    IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE ExpiredSessionCursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
        FOR SELECT SessionId FROM #tblExpiredSessions 

        DECLARE @SessionId nvarchar(88)

        OPEN ExpiredSessionCursor

        FETCH NEXT FROM ExpiredSessionCursor INTO @SessionId

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
            BEGIN
                DELETE FROM [ASPState].dbo.ASPStateTempSessions WHERE SessionId = @SessionId AND Expires < @now
                FETCH NEXT FROM ExpiredSessionCursor INTO @SessionId
            END

        CLOSE ExpiredSessionCursor

        DEALLOCATE ExpiredSessionCursor

    END 

    DROP TABLE #tblExpiredSessions

RETURN 0
```

If the problem is due to an undersized instance and scale up isn't feasible, consider scaling out using session state partitioning.